# Delete a file in Python3 in Windows and Linux

Tags: python-3.x

I'm printing a file which I take from a first command line argument:

```
import sys, os
fileToPrint = sys.argv[1]
```

The file is in `C:\tmp\tmp.txt` or in `/home/my_user/tmp.txt`. Then after I print it, I want to remove that file and it works fine with a path in Linux but not in Windows:

```
os.remove(fileToPrint)
```

When I do this from interpreter it works in Windows with slash but `sys.argv[1]` is a path with a backslash:

```
os.remove('C:/tmp/tmp.exe')
```

Is there a way to remove a file that works for both, Windows and Linux without converting backslashes to slashes?

Comment: the problem is probably the shell; it will want to interpret `\t` as an escape sequence. does `> python yourprogram.py "C:\tmp\tmp.exe"` (note the quotes) work?

Comment: It works with the quotes, Windows and Linux. Thanks!